# Eclipse - skipping missing source code in the debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, elf

When I'm trying to access some code that is not included in my ELF files, for instance - stepping into some external function, I get the following error message:

```
Can't find a source file at "sensor_core/phy/sensor_phy.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Instead of getting such error message i'd like to skip missing code, until the next line of the code that I have the access to.

How Do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it with step filtering.

Go to `Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering` and check `Use Step Filters`. Now check and/or add the sources you want to skip.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need to debug a C code... I guess that the above applies only to a java code.

Comment: have you tried to add a filter for `sensor_core.*`?